# Windows RD - Temporary Accounts in Terminal Services servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, user-management, windows-terminal-services

We are facing this weird problem. Since a restart of the server recently, most of the user accounts are getting created with Temporary profiles.

We followed a few blogs and followed steps as below:

--cleared the accounts from Registry > ProfileList > *.bak

--deleted old profiles.

Even after that we see the user accounts are getting created.

Could someone suggest how to permanently fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the users directory?  If those got out of whack it could cause this symptom.

Comment: Try to delete problematic user profiles thru the Advanced System Settings (Computer Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advanced tab > User Profiles > Settings). Then delete *.bak registry hives under ProfileList in registry.